# Python invalid literal for int() error message when trying to find average of numbers in a file

Tags: python

I am trying to find the average of numbers in a file of integers that are input delimited by spaces and I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "second.py", line 4, in 
> lst =list(map(int, line))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Here is my code:

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline()
while line:
    value = int(line.strip())
    lst =list(map(int, value))
    avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
    print(avg)
```

Here is the input file:

1 4 15 12 8

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1) input the numbers in one line
-2) split the line
-3) convert each number, and add it to a list of numbers
-4) compute the average
-5) print

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline()
lst = []
    
for x in line.split():
    value = int(x.strip())
    lst.append(value)

avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)

print(lst)
print("the average = ", avg)
```

This is for just one line, you can loop for multiple lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You have to use `split()` to split the numbers

e.g.

```
['1 4 15 12 8'].split() => ['1', '4', '15', '12', '8']
```

2. You have to append numbers to the list

```
import sys
lines = ['1 4 15 12 8']
lst = []
for line in lines:
    for x in line.split():
        value = int(x.strip())
        lst.append(value)
        avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
        print(avg)
```

Output:

```
1.0
2.5
6.666666666666667
8.0
8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with:

```
while line:
    lst =[int(i) for i in line.split(" ")] 
    avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
    print(avg)
```